How can I edit Armature in Edit mode?
I edited the armature to fit the model I edited in Edit mode, but it doesn't change in Object mode or Pose mode. When I try to move the armature to a new position, it changes the model. How can I edit the armature to fit correctly?




hello please share your file

In Pose Mode, go to menu  Pose > Clear Transform > All
